# How to setup Client authentication with SSL on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I would be grateful if someone could help me to do the following:

1. create a CA
2. create a server certificate and sign it with my CA
3. create multiple client certificates and sign them with my CA
4. Implement this on Tomcat 7 and make everything working.

I need step by step tutorial since I never did this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
   I need step by step tutorial since I never did this
```

**=>** Read these two chapter's from ***More Servlets and JSP by Marty Hall***

**1.** Chapter 7: Declarative Web Application Security

**2.** Chapter 8: Programmatic Security

The Good thig is it's free. Follow the link [HERE](http://pdf.moreservlets.com/)

Comment: I read it but it did not help me much because I already know how to setup ssl on tomcat with self signed certificate.
I need to Implement CA, server and client keys in tomcat